# ffmpeg av_interleaved_write_frame(): Device not configured

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-processing, macos-high-sierra

I have repeatedly tried to convert several videos I have lying around, but they all fail due to the error msg **av_interleaved_write_frame(): Device not configured**. Since I am writing to a wd my cloud disk I presume it is due to my mac loosing its connection after the keyboard is idle for 15 min.

Any idea how I can circumvent this?

Mac OS X High sierra.

Comment: So if you convert your movie local you get no error, ain't it? So just convert local than move the converted video on your wd disk.

Comment: In theory yes—but I still would prefer the drive not to disconnect.

Comment: Tipically this is due to the Mac power management. You have to setup the power management so that it won't put your Mac and above all your HD in an IDLE state. Just for a fast trial, disable it at all and try to convert to your wd hd. But try this only if you are sure that locally it works.